# How the hell are there an uncountable number of countable ordinals?

Tags: number-theory, intuition

I just read that there are an **uncountable** number of **countable** ordinals.

**How the hell is that possible?**

Comment: ... and there is an infinte number of finite ordinals. So what?

Comment: Hagen's comment here is really the thing to think about - if you're comfortable with there being infinitely many finite ordinals, then that should suggest that the situation may be the same with countable ordinals. Hagen's answer then constitutes a proof that this is indeed the case (modulo the claim that the set of countable ordinals is itself an ordinal, which is a good exercise). (Also, the language of your question could be a bit more polite.)

Answer (score 7):

The set(!) of countable ordinals is itself an ordinal (well-ordered and transitive). If this ordinal were countable, it would be an element of itself.

Comment: contradicting the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity)